# Issues with importing _helpers in Google Datalab

Tags: python, google-app-engine, apigee

Currently trying to run a script on Google DataLab. I am new to using Google Datalab so it is likely an experience issue using this. Any help is appreciated.

The script tries to import _helpers from google.cloud but throws the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/batch.py", line 29, in <module> from google.cloud import _helpers
ImportError: cannot import name _helpers
```

I have tried importing through typical pip install etc. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the output of `pip freeze` in the environment you're running the script in?